# Before the lablel for each of the menu item, there is space with the some color, i want to remove the color

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am using richfaces dropDownMenu component which contains a set of rich menuItems. When the menu items are displayed, a extra space is displayed before the lablel for each of the menu item. But I have a requirement of not displaying the space before the labels and to change the color.

I used the css to reduce the space:

.rich-menu-item-icon img {
    width: 0px;
 }
 .rich-menu-group-icon img {
     width: 0px;
 }

but, i need to change the color in that place.

Comment: isn't this question similar to your previous one?

Comment: Yes. And I think it's high time to learn CSS. @anandhinaveen: don't focus too much on JSF source code while doing CSS. CSS doesn't see anything from JSF source code. Rightclick page in webbrowser and view HTML source. That's what CSS (and Javascript) sees. You can find here a good CSS tutorial/reference: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp You can use Firebug and/or WDT to save a lot of work in editing/testing/debugging CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the itemClass property and assign whatever css class you like to it.
You can explore more options here: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dropDownMenu.jsf?tab=info&cid=14944374